# How can I convert date time format string used by C# to the format used by moment.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, momentjs, datetime-format

**C#** uses string like that `'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm'` to define format the date and time should be displayed in.

Equivalent of that in **momentjs** is `'DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm'`.

Is there some function that can covert one format definition into the other regardless of what (legal) combination of format specifiers source format contains?

Basically what I want is:

```
function toMomentJsFormatDefinition(cSharpFormatDefinition) {
   // should convert all format strings described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
}

console.log(toMomentJsFormatDefinition('dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm'));
// outputs DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm
```

Ideally `toMomentJsFormatDefinition` should be defined in some already written and fairly well tested library I'll just use in my project.

Comment: I don't understand your quesiton clearly. Can you please be more specific? Example of an input and output? There is no `DD` and `YYYY` specifiers in custom date and time format by the way.

Comment: Are you working with strings in one format that you need to convert to another format or do you have `DateTime` objects that you want to convert to strings?  Either way, you should look at the [Cutom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @juharr I have some format defined in C# and now I just wan't to use it in momentjs. I can't do that directly because format specifiers are different in C# and in momentjs. Worst case is implementing necessary replacements manually but I hoped for some premade and pretested solution.

Comment: @SonerGönül I added example to the question. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same task and created the following utility function to convert a DateTime Format String from Dotnet to MomentJS format.

Usage:

```
string lDotNetFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
string lMomentJSFormat = MomentJSHelpers.GenerateMomentJSFormatString(lDotNetFormat, fTolerant: true, fCulture: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

MessageBox.Show(lMomentJSFormat);
// Output: YYYY[-]MM[-]DD[ ]HH[:]mm
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace XYZ
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class with helper functions to work with MomentJS
    /// </summary>
    public static class MomentJSHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Exception that is throws when trying to convert a dotnet datetime format string
        /// to a MomentJS format string and this fails because we have an element in the format string
        /// that has no equivalent in MomentJS
        /// </summary>
        public class UnsupportedFormatException : Exception
        {
            public UnsupportedFormatException (string fMessage): base(fMessage)
            {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Translate a dotnet datetime format string to a MomentJS format string<br/>
        // Restriction:<br/>
        // Fractional Seconds Lowecase F and Uppercase F are difficult to translate to MomentJS, so closest 
        // translation used
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fText">The dotnet datetime format string to convert</param>
        /// <param name="fTolerant">If true, some cases where there is not exact equivalent in MomentJs is 
        /// handled by generating a similar format instead of throwing a UnsupportedFormatException exception.</param>
        /// <param name="fCulture">The Culture to use. If none, the current Culture is used</param>
        /// <returns>A format string to be used in MomentJS</returns>
        /// <exception cref="UnsupportedFormatException">Conversion fails because we have an element in the format string
        /// that has no equivalent in MomentJS</exception>
        /// <exception cref="FormatException">fText is no valid DateTime format string in dotnet</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">fText is null</exception>
        public static string GenerateMomentJSFormatString(string fText, bool fTolerant = true, CultureInfo fCulture = null)
        {
            fCulture = fCulture ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            string lResult;

            if(fText == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fText");
            }

            if(fText.Length == 0)
            {
                lResult = "";
            }
            if (fText.Length == 1)
            {
                lResult = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromStandardFormat(fText, fTolerant, fCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                lResult = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fText, fTolerant, fCulture);
            }

            return lResult;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// State of StateMachine while scanning Format DateTime string
        /// </summary>
        private enum State
        {
            None,
            LowerD1,
            LowerD2,
            LowerD3,
            LowerD4,
            LowerF1,
            LowerF2,
            LowerF3,
            LowerF4,
            LowerF5,
            LowerF6,
            LowerF7,
            CapitalF1,
            CapitalF2,
            CapitalF3,
            CapitalF4,
            CapitalF5,
            CapitalF6,
            CapitalF7,
            LowerG,
            LowerH1,
            LowerH2,
            CapitalH1,
            CapitalH2,
            CapitalK,
            LowerM1,
            LowerM2,
            CapitalM1,
            CapitalM2,
            CapitalM3,
            CapitalM4,
            LowerS1,
            LowerS2,
            LowerT1,
            LowerT2,
            LowerY1,
            LowerY2,
            LowerY3,
            LowerY4,
            LowerY5,
            LowerZ1,
            LowerZ2,
            LowerZ3,
            InSingleQuoteLiteral,
            InDoubleQuoteLiteral,
            EscapeSequence
        }

        private static string GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(string fText, bool fTolerant, CultureInfo fCulture)
        {
            StringBuilder lResult = new StringBuilder();

            State lState = State.None;
            StringBuilder lTokenBuffer = new StringBuilder();

            var ChangeState = new Action<State>((State fNewState) =>
            {
                switch (lState)
                {
                    case State.LowerD1:
                        lResult.Append("D");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD2:
                        lResult.Append("DD");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD3:
                        lResult.Append("ddd");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD4:
                        lResult.Append("dddd");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF1:
                    case State.CapitalF1:
                        lResult.Append("S");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF2:
                    case State.CapitalF2:
                        lResult.Append("SS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF3:
                    case State.CapitalF3:
                        lResult.Append("SSS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF4:
                    case State.CapitalF4:
                        lResult.Append("SSSS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF5:
                    case State.CapitalF5:
                        lResult.Append("SSSSS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF6:
                    case State.CapitalF6:
                        lResult.Append("SSSSSS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerF7:
                    case State.CapitalF7:
                        lResult.Append("SSSSSSS");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerG:
                        throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Era not supported in MomentJS");
                    case State.LowerH1:
                        lResult.Append("h");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerH2:
                        lResult.Append("hh");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalH1:
                        lResult.Append("H");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalH2:
                        lResult.Append("HH");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerM1:
                        lResult.Append("m");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerM2:
                        lResult.Append("mm");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM1:
                        lResult.Append("M");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM2:
                        lResult.Append("MM");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM3:
                        lResult.Append("MMM");
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM4:
                        lResult.Append("MMMM");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerS1:
                        lResult.Append("s");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerS2:
                        lResult.Append("ss");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerT1:
                        if (fTolerant)
                        {
                            lResult.Append("A");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Single Letter AM/PM not supported in MomentJS");
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.LowerT2:
                        lResult.Append("A");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerY1:
                        if (fTolerant)
                        {
                            lResult.Append("YY");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Single Letter Year not supported in MomentJS");
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.LowerY2:
                        lResult.Append("YY");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerY3:
                        if (fTolerant)
                        {
                            lResult.Append("YYYY");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Three Letter Year not supported in MomentJS");
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.LowerY4:
                        lResult.Append("YYYY");
                        break;
                    case State.LowerY5:
                        if(fTolerant)
                        {
                            lResult.Append("Y");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Five or more Letter Year not supported in MomentJS");
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.LowerZ1:
                    case State.LowerZ2:
                        if (fTolerant)
                        {
                            lResult.Append("ZZ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Hours offset not supported in MomentJS");
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.LowerZ3:
                        lResult.Append("Z");
                        break;
                    case State.InSingleQuoteLiteral:
                    case State.InDoubleQuoteLiteral:
                    case State.EscapeSequence:
                        foreach (var lCharacter in lTokenBuffer.ToString())
                        {
                            lResult.Append("[" + lCharacter + "]");
                        }
                        break;
                }

                lTokenBuffer.Clear();
                lState = fNewState;
            }); // End ChangeState

            foreach (var character in fText)
            {
                if (lState == State.EscapeSequence)
                {
                    lTokenBuffer.Append(character);
                    ChangeState(State.None);
                }
                else if (lState == State.InDoubleQuoteLiteral)
                {
                    if (character == '\"')
                    {
                        ChangeState(State.None);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lTokenBuffer.Append(character);
                    }
                }
                else if (lState == State.InSingleQuoteLiteral)
                {
                    if (character == '\'')
                    {
                        ChangeState(State.None);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lTokenBuffer.Append(character);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (character)
                    {
                        case 'd':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerD1:
                                    lState = State.LowerD2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerD2:
                                    lState = State.LowerD3;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerD3:
                                    lState = State.LowerD4;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerD4:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerD1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerF1:
                                    lState = State.LowerF2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF2:
                                    lState = State.LowerF3;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF3:
                                    lState = State.LowerF4;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF4:
                                    lState = State.LowerF5;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF5:
                                    lState = State.LowerF6;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF6:
                                    lState = State.LowerF7;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerF7:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerF1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'F':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.CapitalF1:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF2;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF2:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF3;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF3:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF4;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF4:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF5;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF5:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF6;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF6:
                                    lState = State.CapitalF7;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalF7:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.CapitalF1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'g':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerG:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerG);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'h':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerH1:
                                    lState = State.LowerH2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerH2:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerH1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'H':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.CapitalH1:
                                    lState = State.CapitalH2;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalH2:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.CapitalH1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'K':
                            ChangeState(State.None);
                            if (fTolerant)
                            {
                                lResult.Append("Z");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new UnsupportedFormatException("TimeZoneInformation not supported in MomentJS");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'm':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerM1:
                                    lState = State.LowerM2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerM2:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerM1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'M':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.CapitalM1:
                                    lState = State.CapitalM2;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalM2:
                                    lState = State.CapitalM3;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalM3:
                                    lState = State.CapitalM4;
                                    break;
                                case State.CapitalM4:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.CapitalM1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 's':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerS1:
                                    lState = State.LowerS2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerS2:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerS1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 't':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerT1:
                                    lState = State.LowerT2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerT2:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerT1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'y':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerY1:
                                    lState = State.LowerY2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerY2:
                                    lState = State.LowerY3;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerY3:
                                    lState = State.LowerY4;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerY4:
                                    lState = State.LowerY5;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerY5:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerY1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'z':
                            switch (lState)
                            {
                                case State.LowerZ1:
                                    lState = State.LowerZ2;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerZ2:
                                    lState = State.LowerZ3;
                                    break;
                                case State.LowerZ3:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ChangeState(State.LowerZ1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case ':':
                            ChangeState(State.None);
                            lResult.Append("[" + fCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator + "]");
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            ChangeState(State.None);
                            lResult.Append("[" + fCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator + "]");
                            break;
                        case '\"':
                            ChangeState(State.InDoubleQuoteLiteral);
                            break;
                        case '\'':
                            ChangeState(State.InSingleQuoteLiteral);
                            break;
                        case '%':
                            ChangeState(State.None);
                            break;
                        case '\\':
                            ChangeState(State.EscapeSequence);
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.None);
                            lResult.Append("[" + character + "]");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (lState == State.EscapeSequence || lState == State.InDoubleQuoteLiteral || lState == State.InSingleQuoteLiteral)
            {
                throw new FormatException("Invalid Format String");
            }

            ChangeState(State.None);


            return lResult.ToString();
        }

        private static string GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromStandardFormat(string fText, bool fTolerant, CultureInfo fCulture)
        {
            string result;

            switch (fText)
            {
                case "d":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "f":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern + " " + fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "F":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "g":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "G":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + fCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "M":
                case "m":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "O":
                case "o":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK", fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "R":
                case "r":
                    throw new UnsupportedFormatException("RFC 1123 not supported  in MomentJS");
                case "s":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.SortableDateTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "t":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "T":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                case "u":
                    throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Universal Sortable Format not supported in MomentJS");
                case "U":
                    throw new UnsupportedFormatException("Universal Fulll Format not supported in MomentJS");
                case "Y":
                case "y":
                    result = GenerateMomentJSFormatStringFromUserFormat(fCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern, fTolerant, fCulture);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new FormatException("Unknown Standard DateTime Format");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```