# Convert date and time format string from moment.js to C# format

Tags: c#, momentjs, datetime-format

Is there any existing function/library to convert date and time format from `moment.js` to `C#`?

I will receive date and time format (only the format, without date and time value) from `moment.js` and need to display it in `C#`.

For example:

```
YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A
//this is the format received from moment.js
```

Then, if I have a `DateTime` in `C#`, I need to display it as

```
2018-06-14 2:30 PM
//this is equivalent with YYYY-MM-dd h:mm tt
```

I need something like this:

```
string ConvertToCustomDateTimeFormat(string momentJsFormat){
   // should convert all moment.js date and time format to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
}
```

then I could use it like this:

```
string dateTimeFormat = ConvertToCustomDateTimeFormat("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A");
//dateTimeFormat value should be YYYY-MM-dd h:mm tt
string formattedDateTime = myDateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat);
Console.WriteLine(formattedDateTime);
// output will be 2018-06-14 2:30 PM
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: `DateTime.ToString("format")` or `String.Format("{0:format}", date)` should be enough, i.e. `"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt"`.

Comment: In the first place I don't even know if the equivalent C# format for that moment.js format is `YYYY-MM-dd h:mm tt`

Comment: Just compare formats of moment.js from [https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) and C# from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and then you can create your own mapping if you decide to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a function to convert date and time format from `C#` to `moment.js` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41653618/3982672). So, I create a function to do the opposite (from `moment.js` to `C#`) based on that. I post it here in case someone also need it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to help convert moment.js date and time format to C# format
/// </summary>
public static class MomentJSConverter
{
    private enum State
    {
        None,
        LowerA,
        CapitalA,
        LowerD1,
        LowerD2,
        LowerD3,
        LowerD4,
        CapitalD1,
        CapitalD2,
        LowerH1,
        LowerH2,
        CapitalH1,
        CapitalH2,
        LowerM1,
        LowerM2,
        CapitalM1,
        CapitalM2,
        CapitalM3,
        CapitalM4,
        LowerS1,
        LowerS2,
        CapitalS1,
        CapitalS2,
        CapitalS3,
        CapitalS4,
        CapitalS5,
        CapitalS6,
        CapitalS7,
        CapitalY1,
        CapitalY2,
        CapitalY3,
        CapitalY4,
        CapitalZ
    }

    public static string GenerateCSharpFormatString(string momentJsFormat)
    {
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        State resultState = State.None;
        StringBuilder tokenBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        var ChangeState = new Action<State>((State fNewState) =>
        {
            switch (resultState)
            {
                case State.LowerA:
                case State.CapitalA:
                    resultBuilder.Append("tt");
                    break;
                case State.LowerD3:
                    resultBuilder.Append("ddd");
                    break;
                case State.LowerD4:
                    resultBuilder.Append("dddd");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalD1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("d");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalD2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("dd");
                    break;
                case State.LowerH1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("h");
                    break;
                case State.LowerH2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("hh");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalH1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("H");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalH2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("HH");
                    break;
                case State.LowerM1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("m");
                    break;
                case State.LowerM2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("mm");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalM1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("M");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalM2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("MM");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalM3:
                    resultBuilder.Append("MMM");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalM4:
                    resultBuilder.Append("MMMM");
                    break;
                case State.LowerS1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("s");
                    break;
                case State.LowerS2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("ss");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS1:
                    resultBuilder.Append("f");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("ff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS3:
                    resultBuilder.Append("fff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS4:
                    resultBuilder.Append("ffff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS5:
                    resultBuilder.Append("fffff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS6:
                    resultBuilder.Append("ffffff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalS7:
                    resultBuilder.Append("fffffff");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalY2:
                    resultBuilder.Append("yy");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalY4:
                    resultBuilder.Append("yyyy");
                    break;
                case State.CapitalZ:
                    resultBuilder.Append("zzz");
                    break;
            }

            tokenBuffer.Clear();
            resultState = fNewState;
        });

        foreach (var character in momentJsFormat)
        {
            switch (character)
            {
                case 'a':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.LowerA:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.LowerA);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalA:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalA);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.LowerD1:
                            resultState = State.LowerD2;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerD2:
                            resultState = State.LowerD3;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerD3:
                            resultState = State.LowerD4;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerD4:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.LowerD1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalD1:
                            resultState = State.CapitalD2;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalD2:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalD1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.LowerH1:
                            resultState = State.LowerH2;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerH2:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.LowerH1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalH1:
                            resultState = State.CapitalH2;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalH2:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalH1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.LowerM1:
                            resultState = State.LowerM2;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerM2:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.LowerM1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalM1:
                            resultState = State.CapitalM2;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalM2:
                            resultState = State.CapitalM3;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalM3:
                            resultState = State.CapitalM4;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalM4:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalM1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 's':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.LowerS1:
                            resultState = State.LowerS2;
                            break;
                        case State.LowerS2:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.LowerS1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalS1:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS2;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS2:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS3;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS3:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS4;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS4:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS5;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS5:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS6;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS6:
                            resultState = State.CapitalS7;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalS7:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalS1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalY1:
                            resultState = State.CapitalY2;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalY2:
                            resultState = State.CapitalY3;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalY3:
                            resultState = State.CapitalY4;
                            break;
                        case State.CapitalY4:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalY1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Z':
                    switch (resultState)
                    {
                        case State.CapitalZ:
                            break;
                        default:
                            ChangeState(State.CapitalZ);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    ChangeState(State.None);
                    resultBuilder.Append(character);
                    break;
            }
        }

        ChangeState(State.None);
        return resultBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added support for literal strings.

```
public static class MomentJSConverter
{
private enum State
{
    None,
    LowerA,
    CapitalA,
    LowerD1,
    LowerD2,
    LowerD3,
    LowerD4,
    CapitalD1,
    CapitalD2,
    LowerH1,
    LowerH2,
    CapitalH1,
    CapitalH2,
    LowerM1,
    LowerM2,
    CapitalM1,
    CapitalM2,
    CapitalM3,
    CapitalM4,
    LowerS1,
    LowerS2,
    CapitalS1,
    CapitalS2,
    CapitalS3,
    CapitalS4,
    CapitalS5,
    CapitalS6,
    CapitalS7,
    CapitalY1,
    CapitalY2,
    CapitalY3,
    CapitalY4,
    CapitalZ
}

private static string InnerGenerateCSharpFormatString(string momentJsFormat)
{
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    State resultState = State.None;
    StringBuilder tokenBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    var ChangeState = new Action<State>((State fNewState) =>
    {
        switch (resultState)
        {
            case State.LowerA:
            case State.CapitalA:
                resultBuilder.Append("tt");
                break;
            case State.LowerD3:
                resultBuilder.Append("ddd");
                break;
            case State.LowerD4:
                resultBuilder.Append("dddd");
                break;
            case State.CapitalD1:
                resultBuilder.Append("d");
                break;
            case State.CapitalD2:
                resultBuilder.Append("dd");
                break;
            case State.LowerH1:
                resultBuilder.Append("h");
                break;
            case State.LowerH2:
                resultBuilder.Append("hh");
                break;
            case State.CapitalH1:
                resultBuilder.Append("H");
                break;
            case State.CapitalH2:
                resultBuilder.Append("HH");
                break;
            case State.LowerM1:
                resultBuilder.Append("m");
                break;
            case State.LowerM2:
                resultBuilder.Append("mm");
                break;
            case State.CapitalM1:
                resultBuilder.Append("M");
                break;
            case State.CapitalM2:
                resultBuilder.Append("MM");
                break;
            case State.CapitalM3:
                resultBuilder.Append("MMM");
                break;
            case State.CapitalM4:
                resultBuilder.Append("MMMM");
                break;
            case State.LowerS1:
                resultBuilder.Append("s");
                break;
            case State.LowerS2:
                resultBuilder.Append("ss");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS1:
                resultBuilder.Append("f");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS2:
                resultBuilder.Append("ff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS3:
                resultBuilder.Append("fff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS4:
                resultBuilder.Append("ffff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS5:
                resultBuilder.Append("fffff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS6:
                resultBuilder.Append("ffffff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalS7:
                resultBuilder.Append("fffffff");
                break;
            case State.CapitalY2:
                resultBuilder.Append("yy");
                break;
            case State.CapitalY4:
                resultBuilder.Append("yyyy");
                break;
            case State.CapitalZ:
                resultBuilder.Append("zzz");
                break;
        }

        tokenBuffer.Clear();
        resultState = fNewState;
    });

    foreach (var character in momentJsFormat)
    {
        switch (character)
        {
            case 'a':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.LowerA:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.LowerA);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'A':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalA:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalA);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.LowerD1:
                        resultState = State.LowerD2;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD2:
                        resultState = State.LowerD3;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD3:
                        resultState = State.LowerD4;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerD4:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.LowerD1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'D':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalD1:
                        resultState = State.CapitalD2;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalD2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalD1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.LowerH1:
                        resultState = State.LowerH2;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerH2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.LowerH1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'H':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalH1:
                        resultState = State.CapitalH2;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalH2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalH1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'm':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.LowerM1:
                        resultState = State.LowerM2;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerM2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.LowerM1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'M':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalM1:
                        resultState = State.CapitalM2;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM2:
                        resultState = State.CapitalM3;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM3:
                        resultState = State.CapitalM4;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalM4:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalM1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.LowerS1:
                        resultState = State.LowerS2;
                        break;
                    case State.LowerS2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.LowerS1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'S':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalS1:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS2;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS2:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS3;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS3:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS4;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS4:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS5;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS5:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS6;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS6:
                        resultState = State.CapitalS7;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalS7:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalS1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'Y':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalY1:
                        resultState = State.CapitalY2;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalY2:
                        resultState = State.CapitalY3;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalY3:
                        resultState = State.CapitalY4;
                        break;
                    case State.CapitalY4:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalY1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'Z':
                switch (resultState)
                {
                    case State.CapitalZ:
                        break;
                    default:
                        ChangeState(State.CapitalZ);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                ChangeState(State.None);
                resultBuilder.Append(character);
                break;
        }
    }

    ChangeState(State.None);
    return resultBuilder.ToString();
}

public static string GenerateCSharpFormatString(string momentJsFormat){
    string[] subStrs = Regex.Split(momentJsFormat, @"(\[[^\]]+\])");
    var res = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var subStr in subStrs){
        if(subStr.Contains("[")){
            res.Append(Regex.Replace(subStr, @"[\[\]]", "'"));
        }else{
            res.Append(InnerGenerateCSharpFormatString(subStr));
        }
    }
    return res.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: In addition, to correctly translate names of months for example, is required to add CultureInfo. And there's still a difference in the meridians, e.g. in locale  'br'  (brazil).