# c# How to extract just the format from a string containing a format (e.g. string = "Printed on {0:dd MMM yyyy}" and I want dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, format

If I have a string that contains a format e.g. below (note I cannot change this string format)

```
var str = "FormatedDate:Printed {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}"
```

and I need to extract just the format e.g.

```
"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

I know I can do this using string manipulation or regex but is there a .Net way of doing this using `string`/`format` etc. E.g. instead of inserting a given string into the format I need to extract that format.

Many thanks

Comment: i dont believe .Net provides magic. If you have a string thats non-generic (like yours), you will have to do some string manipulation to get what you need.

Comment: What's inefficient about using regex here? You could at least use it to parse the datetime data, then manipulate the string into something .NET can actually parse into a DateTime object.

Comment: Who said I want to parse into a DateTime object? I just wanted to know if there was a way of extracting this since .Net uses the format to apply it to the interpolated string - so perhaps it's possible to get access to it. If it isn't that's fine I'll use Regex/string manipulation.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: I take a `json` file which contains (amongst many other things) some fields e.g. `"FormatedDate:Printed {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}"`. I need to convert this (actually any combination of using an interpolated string) to an HTML document using thymeleaf to represent the date (e.g.  `<p class="footer-left" th:text="${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')}" />`, thanks

Comment: I suppose that thymeleaf uses a different format for specifying date formats. Look at this topic to get an idea how to translate a .net date format to a different language https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572317/how-can-i-convert-date-time-format-string-used-by-c-sharp-to-the-format-used-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a list of all formats used by using `string.Format()` passing in a list of `IFormattable` objects that you specifically write to log the format that is used.

```
/// <summary>
/// A detected argument in a format string
/// </summary>
public class DetectedFormat
{
    public DetectedFormat(int position, string format)
    {
        Position = position;
        Format = format;
    }

    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Implements IFormattable. Used to collect format placeholders
/// </summary>
public class FormatDetector: IFormattable
{
    private int _position;
    List<DetectedFormat> _list;

    public FormatDetector(int position, List<DetectedFormat> list)
    {
        _position = position;
        _list = list;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        DetectedFormat detectedFormat = new DetectedFormat(_position, format);
        _list.Add(detectedFormat);

        // Return the placeholder without the format
        return "{" + _position + "}";
    }
}
```

Sample code

```
// Max index of arguments to support
int maxIndex = 20;

string f = "Text {1:-3} with {0} some {2:0.###} format {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} data";

// Empty list to collect the detected formats
List<DetectedFormat> detectedFormats = new List<DetectedFormat>();

// Create list of fake arguments
FormatDetector[] argumentDetectors = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, maxIndex + 1)
                                        select new FormatDetector(i, detectedFormats)).ToArray();

// Use string.format with fake arguments to collect the formats
string strippedFormat = string.Format(f, argumentDetectors);

// Output format string without the formats
Console.WriteLine(strippedFormat);

// output info on the formats used
foreach(var detectedFormat in detectedFormats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(detectedFormat.Position + " - " + detectedFormat.Format);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Text {1} with {0} some {2} format {0} data 
> 1 - -3 
> 0 -  
> 2 - 0.###
> 0 - dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
> ```

Comment: That's perfect, and is exactly what I asked for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex

```
            string str = "FormatedDate:Printed {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}";
            string pattern = @"{\d+:(?'date'[^}]+)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            string date = match.Groups["date"].Value;
```

---

Without Regex

```
            string str = "FormatedDate:Printed {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}";

            string[] splitData = str.Split(new char[] { '{' });
            string date = splitData[1].Substring(splitData[1].IndexOf(":") + 1);
            date = date.Replace("}", "");
```

---

Splitting on both open and close curly bracket saves one line of code

```
            string str = "FormatedDate:Printed {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}";

            string[] splitData = str.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' });
            string date = splitData[1].Substring(splitData[1].IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

Comment: He asked for a way that does not include Regex. Granted, I tend to agree this is a reliable solution, and we shouldn't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I added a non regex solution.

Comment: That was going to be my solution too but I didn't want to poach you lol. That's really nice code too. I can tell you've been doing this a long time.